# Vnc - Raspbian OS with pihole installed

Tags: remote, accessibility

I currently have a Raspberry pi3 + installed raspbian installed , running pihole
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye

I want to be able to remote to the GUI - not ssh with putty or cmd line from windows 11 with Ultravnc viewer as i use this tool with other devices. I want to also use RDP to connect to it as well. Every time i try to connect to the pi with ultravnc viewer i get error " No supported Authentication method" I have tried methods to fix this issue but no bueno.  I installed from rasp i-config the vnc service and tried to configure settings but still get the same issue. Ultravnc viewer for host-name i tried the static ip address and raspberry pi host-name (piHole1) no luck. I do not want to use Realvnc as it is a trial version and i do not want to pay for Remote access service as most tools are free.

I installed XRPD as well what other remote control methods can i use?
How can i fix the issue with Ultravnc viewer on windows 11 to gain access.

thanks